# Does .bind break $scope in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind scroll for an image so that, based on scroll position, I can change an $scope value.  However, something I'm doing is breaking the binding of the value.  Here's the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/h2popz9t/

```
    $scope.testFun = function(a) {
        if (a.target.scrollLeft < 100) {
            $scope.something.yes = true;
        } else if (a.target.scrollLeft > 100) {
            $scope.something.yes = false;
        }
    };

    b.bind('scroll', $scope.testFun);
```

When "something.yes" changes (because you've scrolled past 100px) it should trigger the "ng-show" on the div with the text "SOMETHING."  It's not.  Though, I know they're connected initially because something.yes has the proper value on startup.

I'm not sure how I've messed up binding on "$scope.something"

Comment: why are you setting `this` to a string? or the first argument to a function? or, is `b` not a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you are calling a `$scope` function, it's technically outside of the digest loop since it's on an event listener. This type of thing is typically only done within a directive.

To get it to work, you just need to force a digest:

```
function testFun(a) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log("a", $scope.something);
        if (a.target.scrollLeft < 100) {
            $scope.something.yes = true;
        } else if (a.target.scrollLeft > 100) {
            $scope.something.yes = false;
        }
    });
}

b.bind('scroll', testFun);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2popz9t/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you use bind or on as shortcuts for adding event listeners (or add your own listeners however) then you need to trigger $apply on the $scope yourself inside the event handler.  Calling $apply causes a $digest to run which in turn will check all the $watchers setup to see if anything needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `$scope.$apply()` in $scope.testFun since when it is binded then it isnt a angular binding

```
  $scope.testFun = function(a) {
                console.log("a", $scope.something);
            if (a.target.scrollLeft < 100) {
                $scope.something.yes = true;
            } else if (a.target.scrollLeft > 100) {
                $scope.something.yes = false;
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        };
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2popz9t/4/)